# PL SQL function that includes multiple tables

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm new to PL SQL and have to write a function, which has `customer_id` as an input and has to output a `product_name` of the best selling product for that `customer_id`.

The schema looks like this:

[image]

I found a lot of simple examples where it includes two tables, but I can't seem to find one where you have to do multiple joins and use a function, while selecting only the best selling product.

I could paste a lot of very bad code here and how I tried to approach this, but this seems to be a bit over my head for current knowledge, since I've been learning PL SQL for less than 3 days now and got this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some sample data (minimal column set):

```
SQL> select * from products order by product_id;

PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_NAME
---------- ----------------
         1 BMW
         2 Audi
SQL> select * From order_items;

PRODUCT_ID CUSTOM   QUANTITY UNIT_PRICE
---------- ------ ---------- ----------
         1 Little        100          1
         1 Little        200          2
         2 Foot          300          3
```

If we check some totals:

```
SQL> select o.product_id,
  2       o.customer_id,
  3       sum(o.quantity * o.unit_price) total
  4     from order_items o
  5     group by o.product_id, o.customer_id;

PRODUCT_ID CUSTOM      TOTAL
---------- ------ ----------
         2 Little        400
         1 Little        100
         2 Foot          900

SQL>
```

It says that

- for customer Little, product 2 was sold with total = 400 - that's our choice for Little
- for customer Little, product 1 was sold with total = 100
- for customer Foot, product 2 was sold with total = 900 - that's our choice for Foot

Query might then look like this:

- `temp` CTE calculates totals per each customer
- `rank_them` CTE ranks them in descending order per each customer; `row_number` so that you get only one product, even if there are ties

  - finally, select the one that ranks as the highest

---

```
SQL> with
  2  temp as
  3    (select o.product_id,
  4            o.customer_id,
  5            sum(o.quantity * o.unit_price) total
  6     from order_items o
  7     group by o.product_id, o.customer_id
  8    ),
  9  rank_them as
 10    (select t.customer_id,
 11            t.product_id,
 12            row_number() over (partition by t.customer_id order by t.total desc) rn
 13     from temp t
 14    )
 15  select * From rank_them;

CUSTOM PRODUCT_ID         RN
------ ---------- ----------
Foot            2          1  --> for Foot, product 2 ranks as the highest
Little          2          1  --> for Little, product 1 ranks as the highest
Little          1          2

SQL>
```

Moved to a function:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_product (par_customer_id in order_items.customer_id%type)
  2    return products.product_name%type
  3  is
  4    retval products.product_name%type;
  5  begin
  6    with
  7      temp as
  8        (select o.product_id,
  9                o.customer_id,
 10                sum(o.quantity * o.unit_price) total
 11         from order_items o
 12         group by o.product_id, o.customer_id
 13        ),
 14      rank_them as
 15        (select t.customer_id,
 16                t.product_id,
 17                row_number() over (partition by t.customer_id order by t.total desc) rn
 18         from temp t
 19        )
 20      select p.product_name
 21        into retval
 22      from rank_them r join products p on p.product_id = r.product_id
 23      where r.customer_id = par_customer_id
 24        and r.rn = 1;
 25
 26      return retval;
 27  end;
 28  /

Function created.

SQL>
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select f_product ('Little') result from dual;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Audi

SQL> select f_product ('Foot') result from dual;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Audi

SQL>
```

Now, you can improve it so that you'd care about *no data found* issue (when customer didn't buy anything), ties (but you'd then return a collection or a refcursor instead of a scalar value) etc.

---

**[EDIT]** I'm sorry, `ORDERS` table has to be included into the temp `CTE`; your data model is correct, you don't have to do anything about it - my query was wrong (small screen + late hours issue; not a real excuse, just saying).

So:

```
with 
temp as
  (select i.product_id,
          o.customer_id,
          sum(i.quantity * i.unit_price) total
   from order_items i join orders o on o.order_id = i.order_id
   group by i.product_id, o.customer_id
  ),
```

The rest of my code is - otherwise - unmodified.

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly the explanation I needed.

Comment: *I just noticed you used customer_id in your second code display, from order_items table, but that is not how it's done in original schema. Do you suggest I add foreign key customer_id in that table?

Comment: You're welcome. I apologize, didn't pay enough attention to model you posted - the `temp` CTE has to be fixed so that it includes both `orders` and  `order_items` tables. I edited the answer, have a look, please.